# How to use Global Send Keys with a Password Including Special Keys

Tags: blueprism

I am trying to enter a password into a Citrix window using global send key events and the username works fine, but I cannot send a password as is. My guess is that I would need to create individual key events for each special character, but that would reveal too much of  the password in the design of the action.

Is there another approach?

Comment: Which special characters are specifically giving you problems? A mapping Collection might do the trick.

Comment: @esqew Parenthesis to be exact.

Comment: How are the keystrokes not working currently? Is there an error? Are the parenthesis simply not written? Parenthesis characters are reserved for normal Global Send Keys, but are not reserved in the Global Send Key Events syntax as per [Guide to Send Keys and Send Key Events](https://portal.blueprism.com/system/files/2018-02/Guide%20to%20Send%20Keys%20and%20Send%20Key%20Events.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it is specifically with Citrix, but I do know RDP blocks certain SendKey events as a security precaution. In either case, you should be able to leverage AutoHotKey via command-line to get around it.

Answer (score 0):

So you need first to create the object to accept the pass that will be inserted into the field. In the start of the object insert the pass as text, do all the required steps and in the process collect the dynamic pass and import it into the object (when you create the action by assigning the right business object, that you created already). Hope I made my self clear.

Then in the Global Send Keys Events action put the variable of the pass you want to type and that is it.